# Initialization parameters for EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, singleton, ejb

I have `Singleton` enterprise bean, which starts immediately after deploy. I packed EJB into `jar` and want to distribute it. I set several fields of Singleton like `private final String initParam = "value";`. **How can I expose those init parameters to administrator who will be deploy my `jar` onto his own GlassFish server?**

Comment: can you simply use `initParam = System.getProperty("prop.name", "defaultValue")`?

Comment: Where should I set this property?

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Did you want the admin to be able to override the parameter?  Or to have the admin be able to read the parameter value.

Comment: Override, or set. I mean, where admin should set this property?

Comment: so the admin would override the default value by passing `-Dprop.name=newValue` to the java launch command

Comment: And if admin will deploy jar to the GlassFish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Environment Entries, these should fit your needs.

Such parameters must be described in ejb-jar.xml:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>YourBean</ejb-name>
        <env-entry>
            <description>Your description</description>
            <env-entry-name>yourParam</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>defaultValue</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

The value of the env-entry could be injected into your bean like below:

```
@Resource(name = "yourParam")
private String initParam;
```

Env-entries could be modifed from the console of your container, normally it is a more convenient way for admins, comparing to property file modification or creating JVM parameters.

Here is some doc from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html