# Init params into EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have to use authentication credentials in an EJB to access a external webservice.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051277) but as far as I understand, the ejb-jar.xml resides inside the final jar, this means repacking to change password, I would like to avoid this.

I know, that I can use `<servlet> ... <init-param>...` to reference a file in the application servers config dir, where I can store username and password. Is there a similar way for EJB?

My next idea is to declare a custom JNDI resource within the payara server, but I am not sure about the security implications.

What is the suggested method to transfer username and password into a EJB?

Comment: I use env-entry all the time - it works great for my needs, e.g. when I deploy the code if its prod, uat or lab I set one to true, the others are false - based on the environment, then the code uses other env-entry's to load appropriate WSDL URL's, username and passwords.  Also, if you deploy your ear/war as "exploded", then (well on Jboss) you can just edit the ejb-jar.xml file as need be since the App Server deploys it as unzipped.  What application server are you using?

Comment: I am using payara 4.1.x, I will check this "exploded" option, if that works in payara, then this will be the answer. Thanks so far.

Comment: Looks [like](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-micro/deploying/deploy-cmd-line.html) they do support it.  If it works let me know and I'll add it as the official answer!  Note, this is the command line version but I'm sure there's other ways!  Jboss, its just a checkbox in Web Admin UI.  And interesting, I'd never heard of payara, derived from GlassFish.  Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12463807/870122

Comment: @JGlass "exploded" deployment seem to be the default and ejb-jar.xml is accessible in META-INF dir of deployment path, so this way will work well. Thanks.

Comment: Cool Thomas - glad it worked - If I was helpful feel free to mark is as helpful  I'd put an answer in - but you already linked to the basics!  Looks like @him also gave you an option - I just dont need anything that fancy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

this is what JNDI is for.  things like credentials, urls, and paths to resources are supposed to be set by the application deployer (one of the assumed roles in an enterprise deployment model) so that the application author does not need to worry about the specifics.

each container has different mechanics for injecting values into the internal JNDI tree.  Glassfish allows you to do it directly in the admin console.  similarly with WebSphere.  other containers will have similar mechs.  then you can reference the value via JNDI using @Resource (if you want it injected) or via direct lookup using:

```
Context _ctx = new InitiaContext();
String _user = (String) _ctx.lookup( "jndi/tree/path/to/desired/resource" );
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I know the "JNDI => @Resource" way, but my concern is, that every application within the domain can use @Resource and access username+password this way (as far, as I know). In my mind, the ejb-jar.xml provides credentials just for a single ejb module and is a little bit closer to "principle of least privilege".

Comment: understandable, but you are then faced with the issue of "too close" configuration.  the design principal of the ee platform is to remove "configuration" from the code (excepting default configuration by convention and annotation) and place it within the deployment context.  as with all things, there are many ways to solve this.