# Get JAX-WS endpoint-URL from config file

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, config, endpoints

I am currently trying to adjust the URL-endpoints of my web service via a config file (because I want to adjust the outgoing URL of my POST calls, since I want to use a proxy server on my web service).

Now my question is: Is it possible to get the URLs, which are written into a file like URL.config, and inject them into the sun-jaxws.xml file so that I can change the URLs as I please, without touching the sun-jaxws.xml?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at this [Init params into ejb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48357426/init-params-into-ejb).  Basically in your web.xml of your WAR or EJB WEB-INF or META-INF respect you have env-entry's for your EJB's which are then injected as resources.  The EJB they're injected into can expose them as static variables, then you're URL endpoints would use those staticly accessible variables.  So, I think you're going down the wrong route with a URL's config file and trying to inject them into an XML file.  The answer to the linked article shows another way, but the OP said my way works.